# How I create column gaps that are maintained when resizing webpage?

Tags: html, css

[My site currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBnln.png)

```
[this is my HTML:][2]

<div class="column-box" style="width: 100%"></div>

<div id="column1" style="float:left; margin:15; width:33%;">

 <p>ALEX BURGER<br>
I am a Graphic Designer and Photographer with a strong focus on typography and editorial design.
    </p>   
</div>

<div id="column2" style="float:left; margin:15;width:33%;">
  <p>EDUCATION<br>
```

etc..

I tried adding margin and padding in css but didnt do anything

```
.column1 {
padding: 50px !important;
}
```

Is there a whole different way of doing this that would be better to get the same effect? I want the text in each column to stay in their respective columns

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please do not share screenshot of your code, but instead share the actual HTML in the question directly. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can wrap each text in a separate div and apply margin and padding seems easier

Comment: I'm sorry, very new to this, have added actual html

Comment: @FridayAmeh how would that look?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [display grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Comment: Have you seen the simple snippet I posted @Alex Burger

Answer (score 1):

Your "column1" is an id not a css class so it should be represented like this in the css:
`#column1`

If you want to use a class you need to add something like `class="column"` to you divs and then add css to `.column`

Your inline styles are not working for the margins because you just put `15` instead of `15px`

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 </div>
  <div class="column">col2</div>
  <div class="column">col3</div>
</div>
```

Using a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) would also be options.

Comment: Thank you for answering, would you recommend over changing the css to #column1?

Comment: if I style the css as: 

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

can i them apply column-gap: ?

Comment: If the columns are all going to have the same styles, then yes I'd recommend using a class. You probably don't want to use column-gap in this case, but you can add padding a box-sizing to make them work how you want I believe. Updated my answer with the example

Comment: for my HTML is used to create the 3 columns

    <div class="column"><p>...</p></div>  
    <div class="column"><p>...</p></div> 
    <div class="column"><p>...</p></div>  


and for CSS

    .column {
    display: inline !important;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
   margin: 10px;


When I try and add 10px to the margin it works for the first 2 columns how I want it to but it drops the third column down but I want it inline,

any suggestion?

Comment: Use `padding` instead of `margin` and add `box-sizing: border-box` just like my example.

Comment: the only thing now is that it has given padding on the left but not on the very right hand side, any idea why?

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues. You probably have some extra code messing it up https://jsfiddle.net/7ka92cLs/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/glittergirl/83rdacwo/

when you make the browser smaller, minimising it from the right for example, there is always space on the left hand side but there is none on the right

Comment: It's because the text isn't wrapping which is normal behavior (especially when making the window that small). Do you want it to wrap in the middle of words?

Comment: How would I do that? Thank you very much for everything!

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word;` in the css

Comment: under .column ?

Comment: In this case, yes

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent{
  width: 100%;
}

.child{
  width:33.33%;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p>
Is there a whole different way of doing this that would be better to get the same effect? I want the text in each column to stay in their respective columns

Any help would be much appreciated
</p>
</div>
<div class="child">
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p>
Is there a whole different way of doing this that would be better to get the same effect? I want the text in each column to stay in their respective columns

Any help would be much appreciated
</p>
</div>
<div class="child">
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p>
Is there a whole different way of doing this that would be better to get the same effect? I want the text in each column to stay in their respective columns

Any help would be much appreciated
</p>
</div>
</div>
```